# Property 'querySelector' does not exist on type 'Document'

Tags: angular, gsap

i was following along some dude in youtube creating a landing page with animation using **GSAP**  ,
but at the part when he uses scrollanimations he used gsap.to() method but the trick is when is use

**docement.querySelector('string here to class name')**

it gives me an error
Property 'querySelector' does not exist on type 'Document'

but it works perfectly with the man .. i did my research but can't find no thing useful here is the code

```
import { Document } from './../../node_modules/yaml/index.d';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import {
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  Inject,
  Injectable,
  OnInit,
  ViewChild,
} from '@angular/core';
import { gsap } from 'gsap';
import { ScrollTrigger } from 'gsap/ScrollTrigger';

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})

@Injectable()
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('secondSection', { static: true })
  secondSection!: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;
  @ViewChild('imageFirst', { static: true })
  imageFirst!: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;
  @ViewChild('imageSecond', { static: true })
  imageSecond!: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;
  @ViewChild('menu', { static: true })
  menu!: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;
  @ViewChild('heading_1', { static: true })
  heading_1!: ElementRef<HTMLHeadingElement>;

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initialAnimations();
    this.initScrollAnimations();
  }

  initScrollAnimations(): void {
    gsap.to(this.imageFirst.nativeElement, {
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: this.imageFirst.nativeElement,
        scrub: true,
        start: '120% center',
      },
      duration: 1.1,
      scale: 1.2,
      height: 250,
    });

    gsap.to(this.imageSecond.nativeElement, {
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: this.imageSecond.nativeElement,
        scrub: true,
        start: '80% center',
      } as ScrollTrigger.Vars,
      duration: 1.1,
      scale: 1.2,
      height: 380,
    });

    gsap.to(this.heading_1.nativeElement, {
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: this.heading_1.nativeElement,
        scrub: true,
        start: '150% center',
      } as ScrollTrigger.Vars,
      color: '#fff',
      duration: 1.5,
    });

    gsap.to(this.document.querySelector('.paragraph'), {
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: this.document.get('.paragraph'),
        scrub: true,
        start: '150% center',
      } as ScrollTrigger.Vars,

      color: '#fff',
      duration: 1.5,
    });

    gsap.to(this.document.querySelector('.btn'), {
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: this.document.get('.btn'),
        scrub: true,
        start: '150% center',
      } as ScrollTrigger.Vars,

      color: '#fff',
      duration: 1.5,
    });

    gsap.to(this.document.querySelector('#story-line'), {
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: this.document.get('#story-line'),
        scrub: true,
        toggleClass: 'active',
        start: 'top center',
      } as ScrollTrigger.Vars,

      opacity: 0,
      y: 40,
      duration: 1.5,
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With gsap you don't need to pass the actual DOM element, you can just pass as a string and gsap will querySelector for you.

so instead of
`gsap.to(this.document.querySelector('.btn') ...`

Do
`gsap.to('.btn') ...`

Should work just fine

Then do the same to the `trigger` object property

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this code exists:

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}
```

I would remove it.

Then I would instead go to your `tsconfig.json` and ensure that `'dom'` is in `"lib": ["es2018", "dom"]` This will allow you to just directly reference `document` from your `*.ts` files, enabling `document.querySelector('.paragraph')`.

Note that there is no `this.` in `document.querySelector('.paragraph')` anymore.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-h6kzqj?file=src/app/app.component.ts